# Does iPhone provide any API for inserting menu selections into e-mail, SMS and Addressbook context menus?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, contextmenu

The Blackberry APIs allow one to insert custom menu items (and corresponding event handlers) into their standard email, SMS and Address book context menus.  Is there any supported way to do this with iPhone APIs?

Answer (score 1):

No, Apple doesn't provide these kinds of hooks. However there are some tricks I've seen - one example is what Twitterific does to tweet pages that you are viewing in Safari, via Bookmarklet which uses a Custom URL to launch Twitterific.

Perhaps you can do something similar by having a text containing a custom URL. I've never tried this but it's worth experimenting with.

Answer (score 0):

As of SDK 3.1.2, no, that's not possible. In fact there's very little you *can* change! There's not even an easy way to change the colour of the title bar!

Comment: Do you know if this is possible on Android?

Comment: It's a lot more likely to be possible on Android given the fact that it's open source and the fact that it's frameworks aren't so tightly controlled as Apple's.

Having said that, I don't know for sure that this will be possible because I haven't worked with Android yet.